# Return from View.GONE to View.VISIBLE

Tags: android, listview

I have a LinearLayout called `my_layout` and a listView called `my_list`.

First, i set `my_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

and i only see the list.
If i click on a listItem,

the list goes `my_list.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

and the layout goes `myLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`.

My problem is when i press the back button. I would like to return to my listView when the listView is GONE, or if i can see the listView , to finish my activity..But unfortunatelly im getting an empty list when i try to do this.

this is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if( my_list.isShown()==true)
        {
            finish();    
        }
        else
        {
            my_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            my_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution.

The problem was in the animation. I changed `android:fillAfter="true"` to `false` and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(my_list.isShown()==true)
```

to:

```
if(my_list.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
```